# Find a 3x3 matrix A such that 5 is its only eigenvalue; A is non-diagonlizable; and standard vectors e1,e2 are eigenvectors of A of eigenvalue 5.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Could someone point me in the right direction? I can easily go from a square matrix to finding its eigenvalues and eigenvectors but I have no experience going the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

For $(\alpha,\beta)\ne(0,0)$ we have

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}5&0&\alpha\\0&5&\beta\\0&0&5\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

The easiest example I can think of that fulfills the conditions is (Jordan Canonical Form):

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}5&0&0\\
0&5&1\\
0&5&0\end{pmatrix}$$